# I'm rarely seen by you

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Our clap is quiet if not silent
>
> We are small, soft and pliant
>
> Always little or no space between
>
> Before your eyes but rarely seen

What are we?

Comment: Great riddle! $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Eyelids. We can't hear when we blink, they are soft and pliant and has little or no spaces between them when they are closed, "before our eyes" but we can't really see them.

Comment: Technically the answer I was going for...  really unsure what to accept as I still feel this is a better fit but they're virtually the same and I can't say they don't both work.  @Eutherpy you got in there first but would you mind me robbing the accept for Vivek here?  I'll owe you a shiny +1

Comment: I also thought @Eutherpy was right? But then he answered 'eyelashes' which means hairs that grows on the edge of the eyelids.

Comment: @BrentHackers I think you marked "eyelashes" as the correct answer by mistake

Comment: @VivecParekh not by mistake.  See my comments.  With Eutherpy being so close as to basically give away the answer I initially marked them correct and commented hoping that they'd update.  Seemed fair.

Answer (score 7):

We are probably

> eyelashes? We can't hear them when we blink,they are soft and pliant, with little spaces between them, "before our eyes" but we can't really see them.

Comment: I was thinking of rot13(rlryvqf) but obviously you're close enough that I'll have to mark accepted. +1